# Where does PowerShell get the newline characters it puts in here strings?

Tags: powershell, newline, appveyor, herestring

Consider the following PowerShell code:

```
@"


"@.GetEnumerator() | %{[int]$_}
```

On my computer this outputs

```
13
10
```

which are the decimal representation of the ASCII control characters for carriage return and line feed, respectively.

[The same code executed on AppVeyor outputs just a single number](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/alx9r/toolfoundations/build/1.0.522/job/vuglu74y7atdt3st#L763):

```
10
```

In other words, there seems to be variation between the characters PowerShell uses in here strings across systems.  I expected the source to be `[System.Environment]::newline` but [the same environment AppVeyor environment that output the single character in the here string, output](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/alx9r/toolfoundations/build/1.0.522/job/vuglu74y7atdt3st#L760)

```
13
10
```

for `[System.Environment]::newline`.  `[System.Environment]::newline` doesn't seem to be the source for newlines in here strings.

Comment: It just took whatever is in your string. ``"@`"`n`n`n`"@.GetEnumerator() | %{[int]`$_}" | sc Test1.ps1; "@`"`n`r`n`n`"@.GetEnumerator() | %{[int]`$_}" | sc Test2.ps1; .\Test1.ps1 <#10#>; .\Test2.ps1 <#13, 10#>``

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl.  It looks like ["AppVeyor is checking out files with LF (\n) endings on Windows"](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/1119-allow-changing-git-autocrlf-setting) by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell script is essentially a string. And it already have to use `` "`n" `` or `` "`r`n" `` for line separation. So, if PowerShell string literal cross multiple lines, then PowerShell parser keeps line separators, which was used inside this string literal, as part of string literal value.

For example this:

```
"'a`nb`r`nc'.GetEnumerator() | %{[int]`$_}" | Set-Content .\Test.ps1
.\Test.ps1
```

will print:

```
97
10
98
13
10
99
```